# Update to use 1st of a given Month

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I don't have any example SQL for this, but using Advantage Architect. I have one table where I have the year (eg 2017), an the Month (eg 04). 
I want to update another table (using an inner join on a field I have already identified, so don't worry about that bit) to be a date in the format of  dd/mm/yyyy and for the day to be 01 for every date used, using the Month and Year from the other table as mentioned above.

[image: My fields]

Comment: Please show us your sample data and let us know what RDBM you are using

Comment: Consider posting the DDL of the tables as well.

Comment: Ok, so am using Advantage Architect SQL, and i've put below the two columns (CalendarYear, CalendarMonth), below from table1, which I need to use to Insert Into, or Update a column in another table (table2) (Effective), which is a date field, but to add to this 01 for the day on each. The join is from a column in table1 which is the same in table2, but I can't show that here as it's sensitive info.

Answer (score 1):

ADS provides somewhat limited date handling functionality. The easiest date format to use seems to be `YYYY-MM-DD`, but to convert from your columns to the date you're looking for gets somewhat convoluted.

Here's an example that should help you work things out.

```
create table #temp (calyear numeric(4, 0), calmonth numeric(2,0));
insert into #temp (calyear, calmonth) values (2017, 10);
insert into #temp (calyear, calmonth) values (2017, 7);

/* 
  Start convoluted workaround here. Cast the result of the concatenation below 
  (which creates a string in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD') into a date value
*/
select cast(txtdate as SQL_DATE) as newdate from 
(
  /* 
     Concatenate year, month (adding leading zero if needed to make two-digit)
     and month
  */
  select 
    trim(cast(calyear as SQL_Char)) + '-' + 
    right('00' + trim(cast(calmonth as SQL_Char)), 2) + 
    '-01' as txtdate from #temp
) t;
```